# What maven dependency for kotlin cucumber?

Tags: maven, cucumber, kotlin, pom.xml

I want to use the kotlin native step definitions [like](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/kotlin-java8/src/test/kotlin/cucumber/runtime/kotlin/test/LambdaStepdefs.kt):

```
package cucumber.runtime.kotlin.test;
...
class LambdaStepdefs : En {
init {
    Before { scenario: Scenario ->
        assertNotSame(this, lastInstance)
        lastInstance = this
    }

    Given("^this data table:$") { peopleTable: DataTable ->
        val people = peopleTable.asList(Person::class.java)
        assertEquals("Aslak", people[0].first)
        assertEquals("Hellesøy", people[0].last)
    }
```

Where `Given` takes a function and is not an annotation. I do not want to use the Java-style like `@Given("blabla") void blabla() { ... }`.

I tried to import the package from the example:

```
package vc.capper.cutest;

import cucumber.runtime.kotlin.test

class SomeStepDefs
{
    Given("blabla") {
    }
}
```

But the package `kotlin` can not be found in `cucumber.runtime`.

I thought the `io.cucumber:cucumber-jvm` (artifact)[https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/pom.xml] comes with `cucumber-kotlin-java8`, but it either does not or it does not contain said `Given`.

This is an excerpt from my `pom.xml` -- somethign is missing, I guess, but what?

Prelude:

```
<properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  <kotlin.version>1.1.2-2</kotlin.version>
  <spring-boot.version>1.5.7.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
  <cucumber.version>2.0.1</cucumber.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  ...
</dependencyManagement>
```

Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jre8</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  ...
</dependencies>
```

*Update* and clarification:

The packages that seem to be missing are `cucumber.runtime.kotlin` and `cucumber.api.java8.En` as you can see from the IntelliJ screenshot:

[image: missings]

Also you can see the list of actual dependencies the project uses:

[image: dependencies]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that `Given` is not a Kotlin specific DSL / method. It is a part of `cucumber.api.java8.En`. All you have to do is to extend your class from it:

```
package vc.capper.cutest;

import cucumber.runtime.kotlin.test
import cucumber.api.java8.En

class SomeStepDefs : En {
    Given("blabla") {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: No, thats not it. I updated the information in the Q

Comment: There is no artifact `cucumber-kotlin-java8` as there is no "special" Kotlin classes for Cucumber. As stated in their docs: "You can use `cucumber-java` or `cucumber-java8` directly in Kotlin." Also, `cucumber.runtime.kotlin.test` package seems to be yours: `package cucumber.runtime.kotlin.test;` in the first file. And then you're trying to import it in `SomeStepDefs`. [The example you've posted](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/kotlin-java8/src/test/kotlin/cucumber/runtime/kotlin/test/LambdaStepdefs.kt) works perfectly when I import in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>` to `<artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>` to use lambda style definitions.

Note there currently is no native Kotlin implementation of cucumber.

Also, the `cucumber-kotlin-java8` you are referring to is an example of how to use Cucumber-java8 with Kotlin.

In addition, you'll need to extend the `En` interface.